# Cannot aggregate Firebase notification events by custom analytics label?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the Cloud Messaging feature of FireBase and I need to analyze the notification data stored in BigQuery.

I have two tables in BigQuery:

- `<project_name>.analytics_[0-9]*.event_*` which contains all the events details [event_name, event_params, event_date, etc] like "notification_open" or "notification_closed", etc
- and `leavoice.firebase_messaging.data` table which contains columns like message_id, analytics_label, etc

From the first table, I am able to group by result based on event_name  which gives me a good overview of the different notification

| event_name | event_count |
| --- | --- |
| notification_receive | 50000 |
| notification_dismiss | 30000 |
| notification_open | 3000 |
| notification_foreground | 600 |

From the second table I am able to get the following details:

event_timestamp TIMESTAMP NULLABLE
project_number  INTEGER NULLABLE
message_id  STRING  NULLABLE
instance_id STRING  NULLABLE
message_type  STRING  NULLABLE
sdk_platform  STRING  NULLABLE
app_name  STRING  NULLABLE
collapse_key  STRING  NULLABLE
priority  INTEGER NULLABLE
ttl INTEGER NULLABLE
topic STRING  NULLABLE
bulk_id INTEGER NULLABLE
device_recently_active  BOOLEAN NULLABLE
event STRING  NULLABLE
analytics_label

What I want is to drill down on each different event_name for example notification_closed based on the custom analytics_label from the second table, but I am not able to join these two relations. I thought message_id contained in event_params from the first table might be the same as the message_id in the second table but they are not.

Is there a way to analyze custom analytics labels for notifications with the different notification_event categories (notification_closed, notification_open, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the analytics label is also coming in the events table as a label property in the event_params column, so there isn't any need to join the two tables in the first place.